# Typescript - Is there a way to infer a union from all members of a collection, rather than inferring from the first member?

Tags: javascript, typescript

When TS is inferring from a collection of inputs, its default behaviour is to take the first member of the collection.

This is frustrating when there's more than one possible type, where ideally TS would infer a union instead.

See the [TS playground for an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSB2AzApgJwGphAV2QHgBUA+AbwChppgB7eCAF1W2HutQAoLLoATMesAC5oJAG5ZcgggF8A2gF0uAShLSyasjTr1o9ZA2gBeaPGQB3OEjSYcydrK5iJyYQEZpAGmgB6b9DwAtAHQAGIAlqgG4rbQAA6o1KJhPMg80GFWqMjwwMiO0ZIiiNTUwgDkAEZgqGXSavJKPn6BQdAABgRt6TAZKKhZaZDt8NgAthVoXezJyFggAJ7pOmbU2CBpE8NjE6jQAD5FJcIMqBkA5tJtSmQ3WgZ6DABMRibmln02uPb5zuUn57UvL5-K1wpEdAVkHEEkkUmlemhsrkfrY3J4yA0miDWh0umEepkBtAhm1-vAzlMZnNFmFlqt1tBNm0RuM0PtoGSKdcgA)

Does anybody know if there's a way to infer a union instead of just the first member's type?

Comment: Sorry I jumped the gun with my answer; it now works with one generic.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by the generic type extending `{ value: any }`:

```js
class InferValue<T extends { value: any }>{
  constructor(
    data: T[]
  ){}
}

const test = new InferValue([
  {value: 1},
  {value: 'string'}
])


const test2 = new InferValue([
  {value: 'string'},
  {value: 1},
])
```

[Here is the TS playground with working code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSB2AzApgJwGphAV2QHgBVpkAPAF2XgBMYBvaANy1wC5ox4BPaAXwD5aAKGjRgAe3gQyqbMDJjUACmEjoVMGTBsCAbQC6KgJS0eg04PGSy0ClOgBeaPGQB3OEjSYcyRTpW0mbzYAckQxMWCeABp-QNZoYKlUAEt4AHNIwT1DQVzLO1syACYHJ1d3FAxmHz8RAOqQpNSM6NiG6ABGVuzBIA).

Comment: This is actually the way I'm doing it right now. The problem is that you get the inferred type as `{value: string} | {value:number}` rather than `string | number`. 



You can use something like `T extends {value: infer Y} ? Y : false;` to infer the value, but its a bit messy; and I was hoping to do it inline or find a cleaner way to do it.